# How to track hardware resource usage statistics on OS X?

Tags: software-recommendation, hardware

Are there any applications that persistently track statistics like those displayed with [iStat Menus](http://bjango.com/mac/istatmenus/) (network, CPU, RAM, temperature, etc.)?

Having this data would be cool on its own, but it would also be useful if such a program broke down the data by day of the week, time of day, programs running, location, etc.

Answer (score 2):

[Hardware Monitor](http://www.bresink.com/osx/216202/details.html) has the features you need, but only evaluation version is free.

> - definition of artificial sensors that monitor aspects of the
>     operating system, e.g. CPU load, number of processes, disk usage,
>     memory usage, paging activity, network interface activity (only in
>     10.4 or later)

Or you can make [Bash script](http://www.mactricksandtips.com/2008/08/log-cpuload-usage-on-your-mac.html), and then import created CSV file into Google Docs or Excel to build chart.

Comment: This looks like a good solution, but not sure if it will work with a 2011 MacBook Air (it says only models through to March '11 will work).

Comment: The developer behind [Hardware Monitor](http://www.bresink.com/products.html) has been leading the pack on supporting new sensors / new hardware with active improvements. It's a free trial, so see what it does. Usually it tells you there are 4 sensors that are new/unknown - but shows you the rest of the data.

Answer (score 1):

I would configure [snmp on your mac](http://www.mikesel.info/snmp-os-x/) and then set up something like [mrtg](http://oss.oetiker.ch/mrtg/) to draw pretty graphs once the data has been collected.

You can have once machine watch all the routers and computers on your local network. Your mac can monitor itself as well if that's all you want.

It won't likely do location tracking - but it's a start and widely documented how to set up and configure both the data sharing as well as the data collection.